# Have I been hacked or compromised from an answered face time call from South Africa?

Tags: iphone, malware

at 603 EDT I received a face time video call but somehow hung it up without answering (I was sleeping) at 605 they called back and since I was sleeping didn't really pay attention to it and answered it.  It looked and sounded like a party in the video so I immediately hung up. The line was open for 3 seconds and I have since blocked the number. Here is the number +27 (64) 6528179. Do I need to do anything to further protect my iPhone iPad and Mac? Thx, Oscar

Answer (score -1):

Nope, no one can hack your iPhone or steal your data just by connecting with you over facetime.

Comment: May I know the reason for this downvote?